# How do I kill a process in the "Uninterruptible Sleep" state?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, disk

OS is Debian 10. Using thunar as my file manager.

I'm assuming some sort of error occurred trying to read a cheap SD card, and now `thunar` is not responding.

I tried `kill -9`, no such luck.

`ps` shows the process is in the "Uninterruptible Sleep" state.

I would like to be able to:

1. Launch a new instance of `thunar` so I can continue to use my system, and
2. Clean up the 30 old `thunar` windows that will not redraw.

I absolutely do not want to restart my system, the whole point for me of switching from Windows and to Linux is high uptime (which it mostly succeeds at).

Perhaps there is some kernel feature that must be enabled, that covers a user like myself. I understand that the kernel is designed to work for most users, but perhaps there is some sort of flag that can be enabled "tolerate cheap io devices" or something similar, that will allow me to use SD cards without having to reboot constantly.

Comment: What happens if you pull out the SD card?

Comment: The SD card is currently removed. fdisk -l prints some output but then hangs.

Comment: Is the reader hotpluggable? If so, what happens if you remove it too?

Comment: You cannot kill a process in that state.

Comment: (Especially to those who see this as a duplicate:) despite the title being about killing a process, it's much more interesting to read this Q as its body suggests: can't we remove the artifacts of a userspace program that's waiting for a process that will never terminate? An I/O subsystem that hangs forever because a drive is gone is dysfunctional: is it a driver bug? How can we be sure? Is there no workaround?

Comment: Something like `xkill` might help with the window cleanup